# Optimize WP Meta Query for large amount of post meta?

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I have a large WP site with about 2k posts and 150k postmeta. When browsing to a large category, the archive loads very slow due to the WP query that is seeking for featured posts, to show them first. 
I know that the ultimate target is to optimize the postmeta table, but for now I would like to know if there is any possible way to optimize the meta query (one at the bottom) below.

I did some debugging (see the `//comments`) and found that the `'compare' => '!='` is causing for the query to get really slow. I've also found that `''` or `'<'` is speeding up the query a lot, with the same results, but I am not sure if that is a proper way to go. Please let me know if there is a way to speed up this query. Thanks

```
function appthemes_addon_on_top_query( $wp_query ){

    $addon_type = $wp_query->get( 'addon_on_top' );

    if( ! $addon_type || ! appthemes_addon_exists( $addon_type ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $addon_info = appthemes_get_addon_info( $addon_type );
    $flag_key   = $addon_info['flag_key']; //custom field for featured posts
    $meta_query = (array) $wp_query->get( 'meta_value', 1 );
    $meta_query = array_filter( $meta_query );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => $flag_key,
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            //Deleting the array below makes the query quick, but i need it to show featured posts first
            array(
                'key'   => $flag_key,
                'value' => 1,
            ),
            //Deleting the array below makes the query quick, but i need it to properly sorting the posts by date (see below: $wp_query->set( 'orderby')
            array(
                'key'     => $flag_key,
                'value'   => 1,
                'compare' => '!=', //It is about this comparison. '' or '<' makes the query quick, but i am not sure if that is a proper replacement. Also not sure why '!=' makes it this slow.
            ),
        ),
    );

    $wp_query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Ive found that  `'compare' => '!='` slows it down, but  `'compare' => '<>'` does not. I guess both are the same, so I guess this question is solved.